# Change the Yes/No Column Type into a Checkbox for a SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, dropdown, designer

I am having trouble trying to find out how to change the Yes/No Dropdown to a Checkbox while in quick edit mode. I am on a SharePoint Online list and have tried a few different things without any luck. See the attached picture for more clarification.[image: Picture]

So when in Quick Edit mode it is a Dropdown containing Yes/No for each row. Even though when I set up the column it said "Yes/No (Checkbox)" for the column type. If someone could point me in the right direction on how to change this I would be so ecstatic. I feel like it is something that can be changed with SharePoint Designer but I am not the best with HTML and JavaScript so I am having a hard time trying to figure that out.

Something along the lines of this following image I created real quick. Each row would have a checkbox the user can just checkmark straight from Quick Edit mode.
[image]

Thank you,
Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look into customizing the list view with spfx, what you want can be done with sharepoint extension field customizer. An overview and a sample of it 
[here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)

Answer (score 0):

By default "Yes/No" column type values will be displayed as drop-down, its by SharePoint design. If you want to display Yes/No values in checkbox then change the column type to choice, follow the below steps,

1. Go-to list settings
2. edit your Yes/No column --> change the column type to choice
3. Enter Yes and No as choice values
4. Select `Display choices using: Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)` , if you want single selection, you can select radio button or dropdown.
5. Click "OK", now in quick edit values will be displayed using checkbox.

The above change did not affect the data in my list.

Comment: Sorry let me try to explain more. When in quick edit mode I wan't just a single check box. Not where the user has to click the little downward pointing chevron and then check mark the check box that appear in that dropdown. I am looking for: User clicks "Quick Edit" -> List switches to the "Quick Edit" view -> there is literally a single checkbox in each row they can click and check mark. No additional click dropdown in each row and check an option in the drop down that appears. Let me know if this is possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To change the Yes/No Dropdown to a Checkbox while in quick edit mode, don't use Yes/No column, create a choice column like the following, choose allow multiple selections:

[image]

Then you can see Checkbox while in quick edit mode:

[image]

Comment: Sorry let me try to explain more. When in quick edit mode I wan't just a single check box. Not where the user has to click the little downward pointing chevron and then check mark the check box that appear in that dropdown. I am looking for: User clicks "Quick Edit" -> List switches to the "Quick Edit" view -> there is literally a single checkbox in each row they can click and check mark. No additional click dropdown in each row and check an option in the drop down that appears. Let me know if this is possible. Thank you!